# Slooze images not displaying

Tags: php

So I'm using a web based photo album called Slooze for some images on a website. All of a sudden yesterday the images show a broken link and even though the images are in the proper directory and I reload the images, nothing will work. Nothing has been changed, there was a server restart 2 weeks ago but everything seemed fine.

I really feel like it could possibly be something on the server that needs to be activated but I'm not sure what. Anybody with any suggestions would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: hmm maybe you didn't change anything but someone did: did you check the permissions on the directory the images are stored in?

Comment: Yea, the permissions are exactly what they should be. They have not been touched.